# Is it possible to write route in Switch 2960?

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

Is it possible to write route in Switch 2960?

In my Cisco packet tracer, I add several 2960 switches in my topology.

[image]

I set a SVI in Switch0,

```
Vlan100    10.10.10.2      YES manual down  down
```

but I can not write a route in it:

```
Switch(config)#ip ?
  access-list      Named access-list
  default-gateway  Specify default gateway (if not routing IP)
  dhcp             Configure DHCP server and relay parameters
  domain           IP DNS Resolver
  domain-lookup    Enable IP Domain Name System hostname translation
  domain-name      Define the default domain name
  ftp              FTP configuration commands
  host             Add an entry to the ip hostname table
  name-server      Specify address of name server to use
  scp              Scp commands
  ssh              Configure ssh options
```

you see, there is no `ip route` in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cisco 2960 Series has supported routing since 12.2(55)SE3 (and later).

The release notes states:

> When you configure the new lanbase-routing  SDM template, the switch
>   supports static routing and router ACLs on SVIs. ( Catalyst 2960,
>   2960-S, and 2975)

Unfortunately Cisco packet tracer is made to give a simple and basic platform, typically used for the smaller certifications. Packet tracer does not support the full features of all switches and routers.

Cisco 2960 12.2(55) release notes:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750/software/release/12-2_55_se/release/notes/OL23054.html#wp1047679